# I'm trying to update user meta but is always 1, What I doing wrong?

Tags: plugins, user-meta

```
<?php function consultation_user_profile_fields($user){
if ( user_can( $user->ID, "subscriber" ) ) {
?>
    <h3>Consultation</h3>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'consultation',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        )
    );
    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
        $hasAccess = '';
        if ( is_object( $user ) && isset( $user->ID ) ) {

            $hasAccess = get_user_meta( 
                           $user>ID,'consultation'.get_the_ID(), true );

        } ?>
        <div class="consultation">
            <span>Has access&nbsp;</span>
            <div class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="consultation[<?= get_the_ID(); ?>]" 
            class="regular-text" name="consultation[<?= get_the_ID(); ?>]" 
            value="1" <?= ($hasAccess == 1 ? 'checked' : ''); ?>/>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'consultation_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'consultation_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "consultation_user_profile_fields" );
function save_consultation_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    foreach ($_POST['consultation'] as $key => $val) {
        update_user_meta($user_id,'consultation'.$key,$_POST['consultation'][$key]);
    }
# save my custom field

}
add_action( 'user_register', 'save_consultation_user_profile_fields');
add_action('personal_options_update','save_consultation_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update','save_consultation_user_profile_fields' );
```

Comment: Probably not the actual problem, but you're missing a character here: `$user>ID`. Needs to be `$user->ID`.

Comment: And what value are you expecting? All your checkboxes has value set as 1, so...

Comment: so value="<?= ($hasAccess == 1 ? 1 : 0);?>" ? this is nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user_meta is not updated, because you process checkboxes incorrectly...

First of all... You've set values of all your checkboxes to 1. So if they're checked, then their value is 1 - and this is the value you save as user_meta.

On the other hand, when the checkbox is not checked, then it won't be sent in POST request. So your `foreach` loop won't loop through them - so the user_meta will never be set to anything other than 1 ;)

**How to fix it?**

You shouldn't iterate posted array and loop through posts instead. And inside that loop you should check if given value is set in POST request and process it properly (set user_meta to 1, if the value is set, and to 0 if the value is not set).

Also, you should not trust user inputs so much - what if user tampers with data and makes some changes to IDs in checkboxes? He will get access to other posts ;)

So I would do it like so:

```
function save_consultation_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    # save my custom field
    if( ! current_user_can('manage_options') )
        return false;

    $query = new WP_Query(  // it's the same query you use to create checkboxes in form
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'consultation',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        )
    );
    foreach ( $query->posts as $post ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['consultation'][$post->ID] ) && 1 == $_POST['consultation'][$post->ID] ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'consultation' . $post->ID, 1 );
        } else {
            delete_user_meta( $user_id, 'consultation' . $post->ID, 1 );
        }
    }
}
```

This way you'll be sure, that users can gain access only for existing posts. You will be nicer for DB also - if user has no access to post, then no meta is stored in DB.

Comment: Krzysiek could you take my small this snippet?

Comment: @pawel1993 I've updated my answer with some code and explanation, why this approach is better and safer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when the checkbox is *not* checked, `$_POST['consultation'][$key]` does not exist for that key. *No value is posted for an unchecked checkbox.*

So `$_POST['consultation']` will only contain values for the checked checkboxes. This means that the existing saved values for the other checkboxes are not changed.

The simplest way to post a value for an unchecked checkbox is to have a hidden input before it with the same name and a different value. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="consultation[<?= get_the_ID(); ?>]" value="0">
<input 
    type="checkbox" id="consultation[<?= get_the_ID(); ?>]" 
    class="regular-text" name="consultation[<?= get_the_ID(); ?>]" 
    value="1" <?= ($hasAccess == 1 ? 'checked' : ''); ?>
/>
```

Or with less repeating yourself:

```
printf(
    '<input id="%1$s" name="%1$s" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input name="%1$s" type="checkbox" value="1" %2$s>',
    esc_attr( 'consultation[' . get_the_ID() . ']' ),
    checked( '1', $hasAccess, false )
);
```

So now if the checkbox is unchecked, `$_POST['consultation'][$key]` will be the value of the hidden input, `0`.

Comment: Nice trick. On the other hand, I can gain access to all posts, if I prepare the POST request - there is still no validation in saving function.

Comment: Right, but this isn’t code review. The question was about values for unchecked checkboxes, so that’s what I’ve addressed.

Comment: Well, you're right, but... It's always good idea to promote best practices and comment on such bad/unsafe solutions in posted code. There's no harm in that, I guess...